# How to find which line in a text file has the most names in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the attendance for numerous days listed on separate lines of a text file, the day of the week followed by a comma and then the names of those who attended printed separated by commas, eg Monday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary.

I need to find and print the day with the most students and that number of students that attended.

```
file = open('attendace.txt', 'r')
for line in file:

    print(' '', had the highest attendance with, '', students')
file.close()
```

Comment: I've made a small change `numStudents = len(maxStudents) - 1` and not `numStudents = len(maxStudents[0]) - 1`, please let me know if my solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you .txt file has attendance details like this

```
Monday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary
Tuesday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary
Wednesday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary, Dave1, Dave2
Thursday, Jane, John
Friday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary, Dave
Saturday, Jane
Sunday, Jane, John, Joe, Mary, Dave
Monday, Jane, John, Joe
```

Then, we open the file, append each line as a string to a list called `attendanceList`.

```
attendanceList = []
file = open('/Users/abhi/Desktop/attendance.txt', 'r') #Enter your file path here
for line in file:
    attendanceList.append([line])
```

We then go inside the list of list of strings, and split it on comma, so I can get back another list which properly comma separated (this step can be done above itself, but I'm separating it on purpose.

```
newList = []

for i in attendanceList:
    for j in i:
        new = j.split(",")
        newList.append(new)

print(newList)
```

Now you will have the lists in the form, [[`day1`, `name1,`name2`, ..], [`day2`,`name1, `name2`, `name3`, ..]

The line below simply picks out the list inside the list with the max length

```
maxStudents = max(newList, key = len)
print("\n")
print(maxStudents)
```

Since the first element inside the maximum element list will always represent the day

```
day = maxStudents[0]
```

The number of students, will be equal to the length of the `maxStudents` list - 1, since the first element represents the `day`

```
numStudents = len(maxStudents) - 1


print(("{} had the maximum attendance with, {} students").format(day, numStudents))
file.close()
```